# mySQL only selecting one line where there are multiple ID matches

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to select multiple IDs using mySQL, PHP and PDO as Follows:

```
$scheme_ids = "23,24";

// get details for all permitted schemes
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM schemes WHERE id IN(?)");
$stmt->execute([$scheme_ids]);
$schemes = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt = null;

foreach ($schemes as $scheme){
    echo $scheme['reference']."<br>";     
}
```

There are lines in the schemes table for both IDs, but it only selects the values for ID 23. The resulting array doesn't contain anything for the ID 24.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

> Multiple values cannot be bound to a single parameter; for example, it is not allowed to bind two values to a single named parameter in an IN() clause.

You can't use statement preparation in this case; you'll have to concatenate the values into the query string. I assume `$scheme_ids` is dynamically sourced from some sort of user input in your real application, so make sure to properly escape it.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM schemes WHERE id IN($scheme_ids)");
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try this way

```
$id= array();
//add value into array like $id[]=23; $id[]=24
//convert the array to a csv string for use with the query
$id= implode(',', $id);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM schemes WHERE id IN(?)");
$stmt->execute($id);
$schemes = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try by defining array as scheme id rather then string, check this way:

```
$scheme_ids = [23,24];

// get details for all permitted schemes
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM schemes WHERE id IN(?)");
$stmt->execute($scheme_ids);
$schemes = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt = null;

foreach ($schemes as $scheme){
    echo $scheme['reference']."<br>";     
}
```

Comment: Jamie Moffat, if it solve your problem, please accept the answer, thanks

Comment: this returns the error: `Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/... on line 14`, but doesn't select anything from the DB.